# в gradle не добавляется зависимость cardView

Tags: java, android

Всем привет, не могу добавить зависимость cardview в gradle. Recycler добавляется нормально. а при синхронизации c cardview выдает ошибку

Comment: А какая ошибка. Может не соответствие версий с appcompat

Comment: пишит   app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath:Could not resolve com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'

Comment: dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
}

Comment: может это поможет -  
Начиная с версии 26 библиотек поддержки, вы должны добавить к вашей зависимости buildscript maven { url https://maven.google.com }

Comment: а по подробней)) не пойму что именно должна добавить

Comment: нет кешированной версии  com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0
доступной  для автономного режима

Comment: build.gradle
     
buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }

и еще проверь -  File->Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Gradle->Uncheck Offline work option.

Comment: руслан, огромное спасибо вам, сняла флажек и все заработало)

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста.

Comment: @ruslan, вот бы в ответ это написать)

Answer (score 1):

Надо Выключить offline режим.  File->Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Gradle->Uncheck Offline work option